# contextInitialized method of action listener not able to call a method on an object . It gives MethodNotFoundError

Tags: jakarta-ee

Below mentioned is part of code of my ApplicationListner class .

Here we created the **imageCache** instance and inside the **contextInitialized** method we are invoking a method on this object.

At run time it gives the  **MethodNotFoundError**  exception. Once the object is created ,compiler does not give any error . Then why does this exception occur at run time when context is initialized?

```
private static final String className = "ApplicationListener";

ImagesCache<String, byte[]> imageCache = new ImagesCache<String, byte[]>
 (IWSConstants.IMAGES_CACHE_SIZE);


public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        imageCache.setImageMap(Map map);
    final String methodName = "contextInitialized";
    IFactsConfigProp iFactsConfigProp =  (IFactsConfigProp)AppContext.getWebContext().getBean("factsConfigPropService");
    try {
        iFactsConfigProp.getConfigProperties();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FactsLogger.error(className, methodName,
                "Error occured while retrieving the Admintool values" + e.getMessage(), null);
    }
```